# Surface and 3d contour in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface, mplot3d

I would like to plot a surface with a colormap, wireframe and contours using `matplotlib`. Something like this:

[image]

Notice that I am not asking about the contours that lie in the plane parallel to xy but the ones that are **3D and white** in the image.

If I go the naïve way and plot all these things I cannot see the contours (see code and image below).

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
X, Y = np.mgrid[-1:1:30j, -1:1:30j]
Z = np.sin(np.pi*X)*np.sin(np.pi*Y)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap="autumn_r", lw=0.5, rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, lw=3, cmap="autumn_r", linestyles="solid", offset=-1)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, lw=3, colors="k", linestyles="solid")
plt.show()
```

[image]

If a add transparency to the surface facets then I can see the contours, but it looks really cluttered (see code and image below)

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
X, Y = np.mgrid[-1:1:30j, -1:1:30j]
Z = np.sin(np.pi*X)*np.sin(np.pi*Y)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap="autumn_r", lw=0.5, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.5)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, lw=3, cmap="autumn_r", linestyles="solid", offset=-1)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, lw=3, colors="k", linestyles="solid")
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Question:** Is there a way to obtain this result in `matplotlib`? The shading is not necessary, though.

Comment: If you set the alpha of your contours to a small value it might look less cluttered.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently it is a bug, if you try this

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
X, Y = np.mgrid[-1:1:30j, -1:1:30j]
Z = np.sin(np.pi*X)*np.sin(np.pi*Y)


ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap="autumn_r", lw=0, rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z+1, 10, lw=3, colors="k", linestyles="solid")
plt.show()
```

And rotate around, you will see the contour lines disappearing when they shouldn't

Comment: I'm sorry; I don't understand the conclusion of your answer. Is this a workaround for the bug (i.e. a certain rotation angle allows the contours to show)? Or is it hopeless to try to display both plot_surface and contours?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to set the offset to the contour :

```
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, offset=-1, lw=3, colors="k", linestyles="solid", alpha=0.5)
```

See this example for more:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contour3d_demo3.html

And the docs here:

http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#contour-plots

> offset: If specified plot a projection of the contour lines on this position in plane normal to zdir

Note, `zdir = 'z'` by default, but you can project in the x or y direction be setting the `zdir` accordingly.

Comment: Not really, this will plot the contour in 2D. But not in 3D as I want them. See the example image, it has white contours.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I misunderstood the question