# How can I plot 3D contour lines in python?

Tags: python, plotly

[image]I want to plot 3D contour lines in python.

I have a (50,50,50)-shaped data. (f(x,y,z)=data)

Using this, I want to draw contour lines, and each line with the same color.

I can draw about 2-dimensional data, but I don't know how to handle 3-dimensional data.

I use the library plotly, But this is surface plot.

I want to get lines.

Which library should I use?

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

n = 50

x = np.linspace(-8,8,n)
y = np.linspace(-8,8,n)
z = np.linspace(0,20,n)

X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)

Bstr = np.loadtxt("Bstr.txt", delimiter=',')

Bstr2 = np.zeros(n**3).reshape(n,n,n)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(n):
            Bstr2[i][j][k] = Bstr[n**2*i+n*j+k]
            
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Isosurface(
    x=X.flatten(),
    y=Y.flatten(),
    z=Z.flatten(),
    value=Bstr2.flatten(),
    
    opacity=0.5,
    surface_count=7, # number of isosurfaces, 2 by default: only min and max
    colorbar_nticks=5, # colorbar ticks correspond to isosurface values
    caps=dict(x_show=False, y_show=False)
    ))
fig.show()
```

Comment: I recommend matplotlib's [contour](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html) method. [Here is a 3d example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445424/surface-and-3d-contour-in-matplotlib)